# Having issues with expo and linking to mailto

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, expo

I am having an issue using the mailto link when I use the following:

```
Linking.openURL(‘mailto:support@test.com’);
```

I get `Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘boolean java.lang.String.endsWith(java.lang.String)’ on a null object reference` error.

```
Linking.openURL(‘mailto://support@test.com’)
```

Above is able to open the email client, but the address it sends to is always **//support@test.com** with the slashes included.
I have looked through the docs, and support forums on expo, but can't find an answer.

[This is the screen I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na3UB.jpg)

I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy s8+ and I don’t know if this is Android specific. In an iPhone sim I just get a promise rejection, which makes sense because it doesn’t have the email app.

Comment: Working for me with Linking.openURL(‘mailto:support@test.com’);

Answer (score 3):

I would try adding a `catch` statement to your call to `openURL` like this:

```
Linking.openURL('mailto:support@test.com').catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

This will at least let your app fail gracefully and log the issue.

Also no need for the slashes on a `mail:` URL

In my case I was getting an error because I was using a simulator with no mail app installed.

I suspect yours might be a similar case to mine but the error message will be able to tell you more.

Comment: Your answer helped me alot but how to i ask the user whether they would like to open the gmail app or the mail app ?

Comment: @kd12345 you could show a confirm dialog box and on confirm send them to the gmail app using the app scheme (I.e. appscheme://)

Comment: Hi Dusting thank you for getting back to me. I am currently working with react native will that work? and is it possible to provide me with an example

Comment: @kd12345 yes that will work just fine. I just looked in up and I think the app scheme for gmail is “inbox-gmail://“ so first try navigating directly to that url and see if it works. If it does, showing a confirm dialog is pretty standard, and send them to the gmail url scheme if they hit confirm

Comment: hi, by confirm dialog do you mean an alert box?

Comment: @kd12345 maybe? I’m not too sure if you can set an “onConfirm” with a regular alert. I think you can do it with a confirm dialog though

Comment: i can use an ActionSheet right? Also, i cant seem to open the gmail app for some reason

Comment: @kd12345 yes you should be able to use ActionSheets, try putting the linking code in the onpress with the app scheme and see if it works 

Comment: The iphone mail app opens but i dont know what to write to open the gmail app. this is currently what i have `Linking.openURL('inbox-gmail:support@text.com?subject=Contact Us').catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });  `

Comment: Thank i managed to solve it i had to use `googlegmail:`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to encode the URL. If you're trying to pre-populate the content in the "Subject" or "Body" fields those values need to be URI encoded for the `.openURL()` function to work.